# std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(mtx); "error: mtx is not a type"?

Tags: c++

EDIT: As per @Slava's request, edited for more clarity. Sorry!
EDIT 2: Trying out @AnT's suggestion (and I have to admit, I do feel like a bit of an idiot for not trying this earlier), I moved the statement in question in to the scope of the function proper and that admittedly vague error did go away. Thank you kindly, sir/madame!

I am working on a simple game engine, implemented the message bus and am currently working on writing a message logging class that will print all the traffic to a debug log to make my life possibly a bit easier.

Now, I'll go ahead and get this out of the way: I am a relatively new programmer and this is honest to goodness my first stab at using mutexes, locks and the like.

Here's the section of the class I'm having trouble

```
.       
.
.
.
~logger() {
        logRunSwitch = false;
        _task.join();
        _debug.close();
    }

private:

    // Condition variable
    condition_variable _lockCondition;

    // Mutex
    mutex _lockMutex;

    // Create unique lock with mutex
    unique_lock<mutex> lock(_lockMutex);

    // The "switch" for telling logLoop() to log the line
    bool logLoopSwitch = false;

    // The temporary string to store the messages in
    string messageToLog;

    // Loop to log all traffic going through the message bus, is to be run in its own detached thread
    void logLoop( auto progStart ) {
.
.
.
```

My intention is to have the function **logLoop()** run in its own dedicated thread, called by the constructor of the class, and print the messages going across the message bus in to a file named "debug.log".

The reason I included `unique_lock<mutex> lock(_lockMutex);` is so I could run with a condition variable, having the loop only actively, well, loop when there are messages to be stored in the above file.

The part *specifically* that I'm having trouble with is the line:

```
unique_lock<mutex> lock(_lockMutex);
```

When I try to compile it (for debugging, as you do), I run in to this error:

```
error: '_lockMutex' is not a type
```

I've been doing the 'ol google tap-dance trying to find a solution to this, and I have found one strange thing:

The reference I was using (from cplusplus.com):

```
std::mutex mtx;           // mutex for critical section

void print_block (int n, char c) {
// critical section (exclusive access to std::cout signaled by lifetime of lck):
std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lck (mtx);
```

Is different from the one on cppreference.com:

```
struct Box {
explicit Box(int num) : num_things{num} {}

int num_things;
std::mutex m;
};

void transfer(Box &from, Box &to, int num)
{
    // don't actually take the locks yet
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock1(from.m, std::defer_lock);
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock2(to.m, std::defer_lock);
```

So, I suppose, my question is this: Which one should I trust and follow? Is one of them outdated? Why are they so different?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Does it work if you write `unique_lock<mutex> lock((_lockMutex));`? If so, the compiler is probably seeing `unique_lock<mutex> lock(_lockMutex);` as declaring a function `lock` taking the type `_lockMutext` and returning a `unique_lock<mutex>`

Comment: "Here's the section of the class I'm having trouble with" - where exactly are you writing this section? Provide the surrounding context. `unique_lock<mutex> lock(_lockMutex);` will only make sense in local scope. Nowhere else. I suspect that you are trying to write this inside a class definition, which would make no sense at all.

Comment: Please edit your question to contain [mcve]

Comment: cppreference tends to be better... but that's opinion. Regardless `std::unique_lock` should only ever be used inside a method, never as a member variable.

Comment: Let me guess: the code posted here leaves out the `using namespace std;` that's in the actual code. `lock` is the name of a template function in `std`, so `unique_lock<mutex> lock(_lockMutex)` looks like a malformed declaration of an overloaded version of the `lock` function. Get rid of `using namespace std;`.